# Chunking An Array of Times (ISO) For every X minutes, using moment

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have an array of object which looks like:

```js
const array = [
{price: 100, time: 08:30:00.0260000},
{price: 101, time: 08:30:02.0260000},
{price: 102, time: 08:30:34.0260000},
{price: 103, time: 08:30:43.0260000}, 
{price: 102, time: 08:30:58.0260000}, 
{price: 106, time: 08:31:00.0260000}, 
...,
{price: 203, time: 15:15:00.0000000}, 
]
```

I want to slice this array every X minutes,
I'm using `momentjs`, How can I achieve this for only 1 loop?

I want the result to look like this:

```js
const resutArray = [
[{price: 100, time: 08:30:00.0260000},...,{price: 105, time: 08:31:00.0000000}],
[{price: 105, time: 08:31:00.0260000},...,{price: 109, time: 08:32:00.0000000}],
...,
]
```

Comment: without using 2 nested for loops for example

Comment: If there an answer without using loops I would gladly appreciate it, from what I've seen you must use some loop to loop over the array

Comment: What you’ve shown is called chunking, not slicing.

Comment: sorry i'll edit

Answer (score 0):

I do hope that your times can be treated as strings.
If not, you can probably work something out from this answer anyway.

```js
const array = [
  { price: 100, time: "08:30:00.0260000" },
  { price: 101, time: "08:30:02.0260000" },
  { price: 102, time: "08:30:34.0260000" },
  { price: 103, time: "08:30:43.0260000" },
  { price: 102, time: "08:30:58.0260000" },
  { price: 106, time: "08:31:00.0260000" },
  { price: 203, time: "15:15:00.0000000" },
];

const resultArray = [];
let currentIndex = -1; // Index for resultArray
let time; // We will save the current item's time in this variable

array.forEach((item) => {
  // If the new item has a different minute than the previous item
  // then create a new sub-array for the new minute group
  if (!isSameMinute(time, item.time)) {
    resultArray.push([]);
    currentIndex++;
  }

  // Push the current item to the correct sub-array
  resultArray[currentIndex].push(item);

  // Save the current time for the next iteration
  time = item.time;
});

/**
 * Returns the timestamp (in seconds) for the first second
 * of the next minute of the given time string.
 *
 * @param {string} time Format "hh.mm.ss.µµµµµµµ"
 *
 * @returns {number} First second of the next minute.
 */
function minuteEnd(time) {
  if (!time) return;

  let hours = parseInt(time.substr(0, 2));
  let minutes = parseInt(time.substr(3, 2));
  const seconds = parseInt(time.substr(6, 2));
  const microseconds = parseInt(time.substr(9));

  // If the minute has started, increment minute
  if (seconds || microseconds) minutes++;

  // If the minute is past 59, back to zero and increment hours
  if (minutes > 59) {
    minutes = 0;
    hours++;
  }

  // If the hour is past 23, back to zero
  if (hours > 23) hours = 0;

  return hours * 3600 + minutes * 60;
}

/**
 * Checks if two times are within the same minute.
 *
 * @param {string} initialTime Format "hh.mm.ss.µµµµµµµ"
 * @param {string} newTime     Format "hh.mm.ss.µµµµµµµ"
 *
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
function isSameMinute(initialTime, newTime) {
  return minuteEnd(initialTime) === minuteEnd(newTime);
}
```

Output :

```js
[
  [
    { price: 100, time: '08:30:00.0260000' }, 
    { price: 101, time: '08:30:02.0260000' }, 
    { price: 102, time: '08:30:34.0260000' }, 
    { price: 103, time: '08:30:43.0260000' }, 
    { price: 102, time: '08:30:58.0260000' }
  ], 
  [
    { price: 106, time: '08:31:00.0260000' }
  ], 
  [
    { price: 203, time: '15:15:00.0000000' }
  ]
]
```